# SAS SQL: Many to many relationships with 2 tables BUT don't want multiple rows

Tags: sql, sas

I have two tables I need to join. These tables only share 1 field in common (ID, and it isn't unique). Is it possible to join these two tables but make it unique and keep all matching data in a row?

For example, I have two tables as follows:

```
+-------+----------+
| ID    |   NAME   |
+-------+----------+
| A     | Jack     |
| A     | Andy     |
| A     | Steve    |
| A     | Jay      |
| B     | Chris    |
| B     | Vicky    |
| B     | Emma     |
+-------+----------+
```

And another table that is ONLY related by the ID column:

```
+-------+--------+
| ID     | Age   |
+-------+--------+
| A     |     22 |
| A     |     31 |
| A     |     11 |
| B     |     40 |
| B     |     17 |
| B     |     20 |
| B     |      3 |
| B     |     65 |
+-------+--------+
```

The end result I'd like to get is:

```
+-------+----------+++-------+
| ID    |   NAME   |  Age   |
+-------+----------++-------+-
| A     | Jack     |  22    |
| A     | Andy     |  31    |
| A     | Steve    |  11    |
| A     | Jay      |  null  |
| B     | Chris    |  40    |
| B     | Vicky    |  17    |
| B     | Emma     |  20    |
| B     | null     |   3    |
| B     | null     |  65    |
+-------+----------+++-------+
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.  SQL represents *unordered sets* - without something to order on, there is *no* guarantee that the order will be the same.  Therefore, it is not possible to consistently have those ages match the users in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the data step merge, except that it won't set the last row's variable to missing - but it's easy to fudge.

There are other ways to do this, the best in my opinion being the hash object if you're comfortable with that.

```
data names;
infile datalines dlm='|';
input ID $ NAME $;
datalines;
| A     | Jack     |
| A     | Andy     |
| A     | Steve    |
| A     | Jay      |
| B     | Chris    |
| B     | Vicky    |
| B     | Emma     |
;;;;
run;

data ages;
infile datalines dlm='|';
input id $ age;
datalines;
| A     |     22 |
| A     |     31 |
| A     |     11 |
| B     |     40 |
| B     |     17 |
| B     |     20 |
| B     |      3 |
| B     |     65 |
;;;;
run;


data want;
  merge names(in=_a) ages(in=_b);
  by id;
  if _a;
  if name ne lag(name) then output;  *this assumes `name` is unique in id - if it is not we may have to do a bit more work here;
  call missing(age);  *clear age after output so we do not attempt to fill extra rows with the same age - age will be 'retain'ed;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Joe! I am working with a large CRMS database and it is unlikely to type in the raw data as you demonstrated. I am using SAS SQL which does not support the "partition by" function. I know the "join" function wouldn't work because it multiplies the rows. And just to add that "name" is not unique, either.  Do you have any other suggestion?  Thanks very much!

Comment: If you're using `PROC SQL` and using native SAS code (and not passthrough), then you can write a data step just as I did (skip the first two data steps, I'm just inputting data for the example).  (If you're using pass through, then partition by is probably available.)

Comment: In fact, if you've got libname connection to that database, it's as simple as `merge yourlib.names(in=_a) yourlib.ages(in=_b); by id;` and the rest - it will automatically pull the data ordered by `id` so you don't need to sort the data or anything like that.